# Is it possible to change settings (change home page (default)) by pressing a link which has a special code for that?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, default-settings, links

I'm wondered if I'm protected from my browser settings change without my permission- by mistakenly clicking on a malicious link that is kinda treat that changes my "start up " page in a browser.
In Google-chrome there's a link chrome://settings/startup  << is it possible to change the settings through link like chrome://settings/startup/"smth that will change my startup page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just by clicking a link, but you can unknowingly change your homepage when installing third party software if you don't read all the screens properly and don't un-check the little boxes that say "change homepage to http://..." or "install browser toolbar".

Comment: but not by clicking huh

Answer (score 1):

If your system is already infected/compromised then that's a different matter, but unless there's an unpatched security hole/exploit no modern browser will allow a site to silently modify the home page setting without the user's explicit consent.